# Dice Which Sum to Primes

Tags: probability, combinatorics, number-theory, prime-numbers, upper-lower-bounds

Let $P(n,k)$ be the probability that the sum of $k$ $n$-sided dice numbered $1$ to $n$ is prime.  It is trivial that

$$
P(n,1)=\frac{\pi(n)}{n}
$$

With a little more effort, one can obtain the relation

$$
P(n,2)=\frac{1}{n^2}\left(\sum_{p\leq n}p - \pi(n)+(2n+1)(\pi(2n)-\pi(n))-\sum_{n<p<2n}p\right)
$$

The case for $k=3$ is not so straightforwardly reducible.

I propose the following conjecture:

> Given $n\in \mathbb{N}$, there are infinitely many $k$ such that
>   $$P(n,k)\geq 0.5$$

For $n=1$, for every prime $p_i$ we have $P(1,p_i)=1$. So it is true for $n=1$.

The case for $n=6$:

$$P(6,1)=.5$$
$$P(6,2)=.42...$$
$$P(6,3)=.34...$$

Can someone give a bound on $P(n,k)$?  I remember dabbling with this problem while an undergraduate at university.  It recently came back to mind and I figured I'd share the fun.

Comment: The dice are numbered $1\cdots n?$

Comment: Yes, I'll add an update